# Free launcher or bootstrapper that checks OS Version or whether .net framework installed

Tags: .net, deployment, bootstrapper, launch-condition

I look for a free launcher or bootstrapper that checks whether the .net framework is installed, and starts my app1.exe, or app2.exe if not. Alternatively a louncher that checks for the OS version.

Comment: ClickOnce will check for you but then goes and installs it for you (assuming you say yes) which, if I read your question correctly, is not what you want.

Comment: If there's no .Net Frameworks installed ClickOnce started an installation, but I want that it launch my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) can do all that: you check a [registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx#detecting_net_framework) to see if the .NET Framework is installed, and the executable is run depending on the conditions you specify. You can also launch different configurations of executable/installers based on operation system version, language, platform etc.

Comment: Is it possible to launch it without GUI, I don't want to install the Framework, but only to start app1 or app2

Comment: Yes, you can use the installerLinker application to create the bootstrapper from the command line.

Comment: dotNetInstaller in basic mode does exactly waht I need. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can we terminate setup process on not finding required registry key ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688463/dotnetinstaller-should-terminate-on-failure-of-registry-check

Answer (score 2):

You could write a native app that checks for the .net framework then have it run the app1.exe or app2.exe. I wrote a blog post that covers how to do this and even shows how add a gui. It is at http://blog.foldertrack.com/?p=45

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a link to the ready compiled application that works from a command line and does the needed checks and launches?

Comment: It is at the bottom of the post