# dotnetInstaller should terminate on failure of registry check

Tags: installation, setup-deployment, bootstrapper, dotnetinstaller

I have very basic requirement of terminating the installation process on failure of finding registry key, during execution of dotNetInstaller bootStrapper. 
I am installing WebApplication and want to fail the installation on absence of IIS.

But it is not working. Here is my Configuration File.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An install check doesn't terminate anything, it informs the bootstrapper on whether the component should or should not be installed. Terminating the installation based on some condition isn't supported by DNI.